# how to create an Ember-Component which will become either textbox, or radio-button, or dropdown input; based on the type of the data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, helper

I have an example list of objects called `properties` as :

```
{
  "properties": 
  [
    {"type": "STRING", "validation": "^https?", "id": "9", "name": "Download URL"},
    {"type": "DATE", "validation": "2015-01-01 to 2015-02-01", "id": "10", "name": "Next Upgrade"},
    {"type": "INTEGER", "validation": "1..10", "id": "11", "name": "Number Of Installs"},
    {"type": "BOOLEAN", "validation": "True/False", "id": "12", "name": "Admin Access"}
    {"type": "ENUM", "validation": "Basic | Premium | Enterprise | Ultimate ", "id": "13", "name": "Product Edition"}
  ]
}
```

An array controller is currently used to display all these properties on the template.

Now I want to create a form in which I would want to accept all these properties as input.
Based on the type of the property, I would want to have input type in Emberjs.

I would want to write an Ember-Component which will become `textbox` for `STRING`, `INTEGER` and `DATE` types, `3-way radio-button` for `BOOLEAN` type (Empty, True or False) and a `dropdown` for `ENUM` type.

Answer (score 0):

define your own `Ember.Component` not `Ember.View`

here is working example:

```
//sample route
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
    {"type": "STRING", "validation": "^https?", "id": "9", "name": "Download URL"},
    {"type": "DATE", "validation": "2015-01-01 to 2015-02-01", "id": "10", "name": "Next Upgrade"},
    {"type": "INTEGER", "validation": "1..10", "id": "11", "name": "Number Of Installs"},
    {"type": "BOOLEAN", "validation": "True/False", "id": "11", "name": "Admin Access"}
  ];
  }
});

App.MyInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  attributeBindings: ['customType:type'],
  willInsertElement: function(){
    this.set('customType', this.get('content.type'));
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each item in controller}}
       {{my-input content=item}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

working [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/honogane/7/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks and I understand what you did there. The problem here is, I wish to handle one more type for a `property` called `ENUM`. Would you please have a look at my updated question and let me know your thoughts on the same? (Note: `ENUM` should be represented by a dropdown list and not a textbox, also `BOOLEAN` would be represented by a `radio-button` or `checkbox` rather that `inputbox`).